# Prestashop - Weird permission error on custom module install

Tags: php, caching, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I'm developing a simple module on PrestaShop 1.7.7.x
iT does well its job of registering custom CSS/JS codes and extending some functions, but nothing too complex.
Initially it had just a configuration form, as proposed by the official DevDocs, then, after following the official guid, I've added a "barebone" admin Controller, in order to register it to the admin Menu on the left column.
Here is the controller code:

```
<?php

class SpecialFxController extends ModuleAdminController {

    public function __construct() { parent::__construct(); }

    public function initContent()
    {    
        $configure = $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules', false)
        .'&configure='.$this->module->name.'&tab_module='.$this->module->tab.'&module_name='.$this->module->name.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
        Tools::redirectAdmin($configure);
    }
}
```

The menu registering worked well and does it's rather simple job of redirecting to the configuration page, BUT, from that moment on I've started having some weird permission issues when installing the module.
Specifically, since during testing I have to uninstall and re-install it several time, when re-installing an error occurs SOMETIMES, saying that "You don't have the permissions to modify 'mymodule'.
Now, I'm pretty sure it's a cache problem, because sometimes it just works, maybe after deleting cache in PS, or server cache, re-logging into admin, deleting browser cache, or simply trying again.

I might guess that maybe I'm missing something in terms of caching (maybe Smarty?), 'cause there's actually no control implemented over that.
Could please someone give an advice on what's best to do usually? Common workarounds or whatever...

Thanks!

Comment: The error actually refers to 'mymodule', meaning the actual name of the module ('specialfx')

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to delete the caches stored at

*/var/cache/dev/*

*/var/cache/prod/*

You can safely delete all the files you have inside those folders.

You can also try to uninstall the module and check the `authorization_role` database, I recall one time that a configuration was left there and I had issues with a module.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, I've tried already removing the cache, but not the DB as you mentioned. Maybe there's the problem.

Comment: Let other users know it it helped you by choosing the answer as the solution if it fixed the issue.